# Cordova run Android issue at SDK tools version 25.3.1

Tags: android, cordova

I run

```
cordova run android
```

And get this message:

```
ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\myusername\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\    
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\java\jdk1.8.0_121

Error: Could not find gradle wrapper within Android SDK. Might need to update your Android SDK.
Looked here: C:\Users\myusername\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools\templates\gradle\wrapper
```

I downgrade the SDK tools to version 25.2.3 from this [link](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html)
 (just unzip to Android sdk folder to replace existing tools folder) and I have no issue (also optional update to 25.2.x also have no issue).

Comment: " i no have issue " You mean you still have error? or are you trying to post your solution?

Comment: You are allowed to post and answer yourself, but this isn't the format to do so. You ask the question above. Leaving out the solution. Then, you post below as the answer.

Comment: i want to know how to resolve issue with sdk tool 25.3.1. When i install it update in Android studio i don`t see folder tools\templates and also cant launch standalone sdk manager (separate problem)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I also found that, from Android SDK 25.3.0 and up, the `android` command itself (under `sdk/tools/`) became obsolete. The command now simply goes like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo The "android" command is no longer available.
echo For manual SDK and AVD management, please use Android Studio.
echo For command-line tools, use tools/bin/sdkmanager and tools/bin/avdmanager
exit 1
```

while the current cordova relies on the existence of Android SDK by executing `android list target` command (in `cordova/lib/android_sdk_version.js` for example). So I guess we would better wait until the upstream fix (so that it uses `avdmanager list target --compact` instead) is done, or manually downgrade the SDK to 25.2.5 temporary.

EDIT:
just forgot to mention that mine is on macOS, while I see yours on Windows... but there could be something to do with it.

Comment: Then here's the update, fortunately:
https://github.com/apache/cordova-android/pull/369

Comment: https://cordova.apache.org/announcements/2017/05/04/android-release.html
We are happy to announce that Cordova Android 6.2.3 has been released! This patch release actually adds support for the Android SDK Tools v26 and newer.